# Simplificar CSS

Tags: html, html5, css, revisión-de-código

Tengo un margen hecho asi ([ejemplo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yorch/zqvumLpx/)):

```
.menu--margen {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: 3px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.menu--margen:before {
    padding: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-top: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Hay alguna manera de simplificar el css del border? He probado:

```
border: 1px 1px 0px 1px solid #f0f0f0;
```

Pero no parece funcionar.

Comment: Que yo sepa, cuando usas `border` con 4 valores, cada valor se aplica a `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`, en ese orden. Veo que dices `border-top: none` por ende deberías tener `border: 0px 1px 1px 1px solid #f0f0f0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Estas líneas:

```
border-right: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
border-left: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
border-bottom: none;
```

Puedes simplificarlo en estas dos líneas:

```
border: 1px solid #bbb;
border-bottom: none;
```

Donde la primera define el estilo de los cuatro bordes y la segunda solo desactiva el border inferior. Además opcionalmente ya que `#bbbbbb` tiene los mismos 6 dígitos hexadecimales puedes simplificarlo como `#bbb`

De igual manera puedes hacer con las que están en el otro estilo

```
border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-left: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-top: none;
```

Puedes cambiarlo a:

```
border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
border-top: none;
```